# Google Chrome net::ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, sometime request fails with `Error: status (failed) net::ERR_TOO_MANY_RETIRES`.

This happens randomly for 1 request while loading page with 80+ resource.

What could be possible reason for this error? I have attempted the following:

- Cleared the browser cache as well as set the option to **disable cache** in debugger
- The connection remains in Stalled state when the error occurs
- This happens in incognito mode too

[image]

[image]

The failing image in above screenshot is refereed in CSS as

```
background-image: url(/images/no-data-5-2x.png);
```

Interestingly, this works well with Firefox, and just fails in Chrome.

Comment: I dont know why but most of the time this issue happens with font files only (woff, woff2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a detail analysis, I checked the Chromium source code for `ERR_TOO_MANY_RETIRES`. And I found the following open bug reference in the file `./net/http/http_network_transaction.cc`.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=488043

The issue occurs in case of self signed certificate only. As a work around one can use valid certificate signed by CA for web application. Further details of the issue can be found by visiting the above URL.

Answer (score 57):

Encountered a similar issue. Site threw cert warning and could not log in with Chrome but other browsers and incognito worked.  Disabled password management plugin and was able to log in even though I was not storing any info for the site.  Resolved immediately and was able to reenable password management plugin.

Comment: THANK YOU!. I just encountered this problem with an internal site at work. Stopped loading unless I went incognito. I disabled Last Pass and the site loaded fine. The site uses basic auth, not sure if that is why.

Comment: Brilliant, I would lost my hair before discover it by myself

Comment: @JasonGerard I wrote the LastPass support. Hopefully they fix it soon. A workaround is to right click the extension icon and select `This can read and change site data` > `when you click the extension`. See: https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/img_5c26699659f9d.png

Comment: Thanks @Tom that seems to have sorted the problem for now. It is happening to me as well on internal sites that are only accessible via a VPN.

Comment: Worked for me too, disabled lastpass and Chrome too_many_retries error went away.

Comment: Same here. Disabling the LastPass extension (as a temporary workaround) solved the issue.

Comment: Same here I disabled LastPass!

Comment: In LastPass just disable the Preference **Automatically fill login information** workes for me.

Comment: The LastPass support told me it should be fixed in the  extension version 4.70

Answer (score 11):

For me it was a lastpass problem.
All you have to do is disable the lastpass extension, refresh the page that doesn't work, and enable the extension back.

Comment: Same with me, Lastpass caused too many problems.

Comment: I've had enough. I switch to bitwarden ;)

Comment: Same with me, with Bitwarden instead.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is having this issue, I found out that at least with WordPress websites, LastPass can cause this issue on Chrome.

```
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
2021-04-12 09:52:41 Error   172.70.34.8     AH01618: user superRootAdmin not found: /               Apache error
```

The IP has a Cloudflare origin.

If the website is deployed by Plesk, this will trigger the Fail2Ban Plesk security feature. So, you'll be banned by Plesk along with the ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES if you disable Fail2Ban.

Remove the user/pass combination for that affected user account and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks, LastPass was the exact reason in my case.

Comment: LastPass has said they have a fix coming on April 10: https://twitter.com/LastPassHelp/status/1380576600572317699

Comment: The fix is "coming soon', as of April 13th, 2021, it's still an issue.

Comment: +1 I have removed all my chrome plugins trying to resolve this. As a developer I was horrified because this was happening only on one site am deving

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you any I encountered this issue today and found it was due to my VPN client which had malfunctioned.